# How to serve using Passenger running with SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I have a Rails 4 application and I want to run it on Passenger with SSL.

I added the Passenger gem to the gemfile and ran the server using:

```
 bundle exec rails s -e production -p 3001 --binding=0.0.0.0
```

In settings I set `ssl = true`, which works. The SSL is recomended and the server wants to call the app with HTTPS.

When I set the vhost for HTTPS port 443 like this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests On
ServerName domain.de
ServerAlias *.domain.de
ProxyPass / https://subdomain.domain.de:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / https://subdomain.domain.de:3001/
SSLEngine on
```

I got this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at  to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at domain.de Port 443
```

The  SSL certificate is provied through plesk 12.5.

What's the problem in this case? What do I have to change?

Comment: Where did you configured the vhost? It seems you are starting rails standalone and using webrick on port 3001, not passenger on apache.

Comment: I'm Using passanger stand alone not webrick. Do I have to run Passanger on apache? Vhost ist set in Plesk there you can set up the vhost settings

Comment: I've done it like its mentioned here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/ruby.html

Comment: Its running now with SSL but and passenger for apache ... but the http version works as well ... how can I set thet http always turns to http

Comment: problem solved! it runs with passanger now!

Comment: Since the problem is solved but there's no answer, I'll vote to close this one as "not reproducible."  For the future, you can add the solution as an answer to your question and (after a day) give it the green checkmark.  This will help anyone else having the same problem who finds the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better and much easier way is to use passangermodule for apache or nginx